# Will WPF .Net 6.0 Applications work on Windows 7 or Windows XP?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

I have to design a simple application to communication via serial ports with a machine and then record the responses in a excel file. The application needs to be able to work with window XP all the way up till windows 10. Is WPF .net 6.0 a good choice?

Comment: Windows 10 is the oldest supported Windows version. Unsupported means you're on your own. Windows XP *definitely* doesn't work. Even .NET Framework 4.5 didn't work on XP. Vista, and 8, who knows?

Comment: `Is WPF .net 6.0 a good choice?` Wrong question. The real one is `Is targeting Windows XP to 8 a good choice?` No it's not. If you do you'll be constrained to just .NET Framework. And even then, some of these OSs won't work - XP only works with .NET Framework 4.0 which doesn't have any of the recent features like `async/await`

Comment: Another reason why targeting those obsolete OS versions is a bad idea is that they don't support TLS 1.2, which is the absolute minimum for every web site, service and API nowadays. Your application won't be able to connect to any web service or API without patching the client machine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The OP never specified, that they needed to make API- / Webrequests. While I agree, that supporting XP is not ideal, you don't need TLS to create Excel files or to communicate via a serial port.

Answer (score 4):

From what I see you will need to go back all the way to .NET Framework 4, if you really need to support XP. I have however never tested this, and you might still get it to work. If you only need Windows 7 and upwards, .NET 6 seems fine. The supported OS Versions of .NET Core can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md). The supported Framework versions for each OS can be found in [Microsofts Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements).

Your specific needs seem to be [serial port communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.0) and [excel file creation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.16.0), both are compatible with .NET Framework 4.

You don't explain why you need a GUI, WPF will be a problem, but WinForms should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I work in a Japanese Company, many of our customers still use XP or earlier. And since my company just upgraded most of its hardware we need to support all new and old versions.

Comment: @リムウェイチェン "XP or earlier", that's horrifying. Anyway, unless you really need to display tons of data points in real-time, the lack of GPU acceleration for WPF in XP shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @リムウェイチェン earlier means Windows 2000. I don't thing any .NET 4.x version would work with Windows 2000. You don't need *WPF* to read data from a port and write to an Excel sheet though. If you want to display a Start and Stop button. WinForms will do just fine. WPF will run but the UI (only) will be slower.  A far more important consideration is whether you can use libraries like EPPlus or ClosedXML to write to Excel `xlsx` files, whether you can use async operations (you can't) or whether you have to stick to .NET 4.0 if not 3.5.

Comment: @Martheen WPF is much much more than a means to _"display tons of data points in real-time"_.   _"the lack of GPU acceleration for WPF in XP shouldn't really matter"_ - it does actually.  This is quickly demonstrated by running it in a VM without hardware support.  Also given that most WPF apps utilise features such as but not limited to _transparency; gradient brushes; animations; glow effects; drop-shadows; custom shader effects; and vector art_ one will quickly notice the drop in performance and be reminded of WinForms.

Answer (score 3):

---

OP:

> Will WPF .Net 6.0 Applications work on Windows 7 or Windows XP?

**TL;DR:** *hardware-based Windows Desktop acceleration* is **not** available on **XP** so there is **no point trying to deploy WPF on it irrespective of what version of .NET you are trying to use**

---

### Windows XP support has ended

OP:

> ...needs to be able to work with `window XP` all the way up till...

Unless you are working for a major government body, support for Windows XP has ended, so **no**.

### WPF requires hardware acceleration

Also, given that you are wanting to create a *WPF* app, a technology released late **2006**, one of the biggest selling points of WPF historically was that it was one of the first MS GUI frameworks to support hardware-acceleration (apps were blitted to the screen in a single operation via *DirectX*) - something that didn't appear in the Windows Desktop until *Windows Vista* in early **2007** (remember suddenly people were buying 3D cards just to run Windows).

Unfortunately, Windows XP, an operating system released in 2001 predates hardware acceleration in the Windows Desktop, so even if you managed to deploy a WPF app on XP, it is unlikely that it will be hardware-accelerated and will run poorly.

Additionally, WPF was originally released in .NET Framework 3 and [required one of Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-30).

### What's the minimum for WPF?

You can use WPF on Windows Vista+ with .NET Framework 3.0+ safe in the knowledge that it will benefit from hardware-acceleration.

### What about the .NET 5+ road?

Given that WPF in .NET 5+ is [Windows-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview/?view=netdesktop-6.0) anyway (thus kinda defeating the mandate of cross-platform that is .NET Core/5+) and the fact that more and more **Windows-specific technologies are either being dropped or not ported in the first place** to .NET 5+, you really need to ask yourself:

**Question**

- *If I know my app is only for Windows and I don't care about cross-platform, should I start to use .NET 5+?*

...to which the answer is a big ***"Be careful before signing up!"***.

The following technologies are not available in .NET 5+:

- App Domains
- CAS (including Security Transparency)
- GAC

...which is a real shame since there are quite a few legacy WPF (and WinForms for that matter) Smart Client projects out there that require these technologies for bullet-proof **extensivity** and **sandboxing** of 3rd party plug-ins.

To me WPF .NET 5+ is a bit of an unknown; it is unclear if it is hardware-accelerated and even if it is, do you want to risk such support being dropped in the future (in exactly the same way AppDomain.CreateDomain [was dropped in .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.createdomain?view=net-6.0#system-appdomain-createdomain(system-string))).

My advice would be to stick with .NET Framework 3.0+ (.NET Framework 4.x+ would be better) if the intent is to create hardware-accelerated WPF apps.

Comment: Even .NET Framework 4.5 required Windows 7 at least

Comment: And then there's the TLS1.2 situation, which requires patching the desktop machine. Without that, even .NET Framework 8 won't be able to use HTTPS to connect to any site. By now almost every site demands TLS1.2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos WPF released as part of .NET Framework 3, required at least Windows Vista.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-30

Comment: The other constraints are far more important. It means even a command-line application could fail to work. What the OP asks doesn't need WPF after all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _"And then there's the TLS1.2 situation"_ - given I said _"Windows XP support has ended"_ such specific scenarios are not really necessary to mention otherwise this post will be a thesis.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _"The other constraints are far more important"_ - I disagree. The OP _wants a WPF_ app.  With this realisation the investigation becomes a simple - _**hardware-based Windows Desktop acceleration is not available on XP so there is no point trying to deploy WPF on it irrespective of what version of .NET you are trying to use**_.